# How to change a CSS created circle for a uploaded image on a loading screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Well i have this Circles created in vue.js who worked as a loading screen, i want to replace them with a image and further, make the image spin.

Heres how the circles are create:

```
export default {
  name: "SpinnerLoader",
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "#0de000"
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: "100px"
    },
    margin: {
      type: String,
      default: "2px"
    },
    radius: {
      type: String,
      default: "100%"
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
       routeTypeName: ['Tela Inicial'],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    spinnerStyle() {
      return {
        height: this.size,
        width: this.size,
        border: parseFloat(this.size) / 10 + "px solid" + this.color,
        opacity: 0.7,
        borderRadius: this.radius,

      };
    },
    spinnerBasicStyle() {
      return {
        height: this.size,
        width: this.size,
        position: "relative"
      };
    }
  },
```

So i tried two things,
first that

```
data() {
    return {
       routeTypeName: ['Tela Inicial'],
       img: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8PfnHfgrH4I/TylX2v8pTMI/AAAAAAAAJJ4/TICBoSEI57o/s1600/search_by_image_image.png",    };
  },
  computed: {
    spinnerStyle() {
      return {
        backgroundImage: url(this.img)
      };
    },
```

and receive a insistent "Error in render: "ReferenceError: url is not defined"

then i tried that

```
data() {
        return {
           routeTypeName: ['Tela Inicial'],
            image: "static/icons/more.png"    };
      },
      computed: {
        spinnerStyle() {
          return {
            backgroundImage: this.image
          };
        },
```

and nothing happen, no error and no image, just nothing.
someone know how to help me here?
if need more info, just tell me.

Heres the html:

```
<div class="v-spinner" v-show="loading && isValidLoading()">
      <div class="v-carregamento">
            <div id="v-loader">
              <div class="v-ring v-ring1" v-bind:style="spinnerBasicStyle">
              </div>
              <div class="v-ring v-ring2" v-bind:style="spinnerStyle">
              </div>
              <div class="v-ring v-ring3" v-bind:style="spinnerStyle">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried to use backgroundImage additional to the other properties?
`spinnerStyle() {
          return {
           width: this.size,
           height: this.size,
            backgroundImage: this.image
          };
        }`

Comment: yah, ive tried that, still no error and no image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t you change the class instead?

Have different class with styles and images. And then toggle the className.

For example:

Markup:

```
<div class=“[loading ? 'loading' : 'image']”></div>
```

Vue:

```
Data: () => {
   Return {
      loading: true
   }
}
```

Css:

```
<style>
   .loading {
      //here goes your loading styles
   }

   .image {
      background: url('path/of/image.jp')
   }
</style>
```

This is going to alternate between classes, so you just need to change the state to either false or true.

Comment: iam not sure how to do that =(

Answer (score 0):

You should return styles as strings.

Try this:

```
return ‘backgroundImage: url(${this.image})’
```

Use tilted quotation mark and not regular.

Good:

```
‘’
```

Bad:

```
''
```

This is because you need to append your variable inside that string.
The problem in your code is that Vue is looking for url() function which is not defined in Vue but it’s a native function in css. That’s why it needs to be inside the string. css will interpret/parse it.

Comment: Did you try doing the same with the other styles?

Comment: How is your html?